# Variadic C function printing multiple 2-D char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, variadic

I need to set up a variadic function in C that prints a variable number of 2-D char arrays side-by-side. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to initialize the `boards` variable with `va_arg()`.

The key problematic line is: `boards[i] = va_arg(ap, char*[][BOARDSIZE]);` The line produces a compiler error (currently, `Second argument to 'va_arg' is of incomplete type 'char *[][10]'`), but basically I'm sure I'm not doing something right. I'm just not sure what that something is. I've tried several variations to no avail. The rest of the code *should* be okay though.

(Thank you in advance for any help.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define BOARDSIZE 10

void showBoardVariadic(int numArgs, ...) {

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, numArgs);

    // Assign an array of 2-D char arrays.
    char *boards[numArgs][BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < numArgs; i++)
        boards[i] = va_arg(ap, char*[][BOARDSIZE]); // TODO: Fix this line

    // Print the 2-D arrays side-by-side
    for (int row = 0; row < BOARDSIZE; row++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numArgs; i++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < BOARDSIZE; column++) {
                printf(" %c", *boards[i][row][column]);
            }
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    va_end(ap);
}

int main() {

    char *playerBoard[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];
    char *opponentBoard[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];

    // Initialize playerBoard and opponentBoard to all tildes.
    for (int row = 0; row < BOARDSIZE; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < BOARDSIZE; column++) {
            playerBoard[row][column] = "~";
            opponentBoard[row][column] = "~";
        }
    }

    showBoardVariadic(2, playerBoard, opponentBoard);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have not stated what the problem is. A compiler error message? A crash? Wrong value coming from `va_arg`?

Comment: You cannot pass arrays as arguments - you always pass pointers. If you note an array as function parameter then the compiler reads this as pointer. This in mind, I feel bad about `va_arg(ap, char*[][BOARDSIZE])`. I would try instead reading a pointer and casting it afterwards to the array type. (No, actually I would try to find another solution. var args are fascinating but in combination with multi-dim arrays...)

Comment: Hmm... `char *boards[numArgs][BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE]` is a three-dim array of `char*`. According to your comment, you want instead an array of pointers to 2D arrays... (I hate this multi-dim array rubbish. It tickles you to master it but actually it has no productive worth. Single dim. arrays and explicit "multi-dim indexing" is easy, robust, and much more maintenance-friendly.)

Comment: Yet another issue: As you print only the first character of boards in `printf(" %c", *boards[i][row][column]);` this let me assume there is always only one character per cell. In this case, I would drop the `char*` and use `char` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I came to the same conclusion like Eric except that I even didn't consider to solve multi-dimension array issues by mere `typedef`s.

Out of curiosity, I tried to write down a working version of the OP. As I finally got one I want to present my code (in addition to [Eric Postpischils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47591963/7478597) answer).

So, after some fiddling I got this working version `testVarArgMDimArray.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define BOARDSIZE 10
#define NCOLS BOARDSIZE
#define NROWS BOARDSIZE

typedef char Board[NROWS][NCOLS];
typedef char (*PBoard)[NCOLS];

void showBoardVariadic(int nArgs, ...)
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, nArgs);
  /* Attention! VLAs are an optional feature of C11. */
  PBoard boards[nArgs];
  for (int i = 0; i < nArgs; ++i) {
    boards[i] = va_arg(ap, PBoard);
  }
  /* print the 2D arrays side-by-side */
  for (int row = 0; row < NROWS; ++row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nArgs; ++i) {
      if (i) putchar('\t');
      for (int col = 0; col < NCOLS; ++col) {
        printf(" %c", boards[i][row][col]);
      }
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
  va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
  Board playerBoard;
  Board opponentBoard;
  /* initialize boards */
  for (int row = 0; row < NROWS; ++row) {
#ifdef CHECK /* for checking */
    /* insert some pattern in col 0 for checking */
    playerBoard[row][0] = 'a' + row;
    opponentBoard[row][0] = 'A' + row;
    for (int col = 1; col < NCOLS; ++col) {
      playerBoard[row][col] = opponentBoard[row][col] = '~';
    }
#else /* productive code */
    for (int col = 0; col < NCOlS; ++col) {
      playerBoard[row][col] = opponentBoard[row][col] = '~';
    }
#endif /* 1 */
  }
  showBoardVariadic(2, playerBoard, opponentBoard);
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

Before I got it working there were issues which I tried solve in VS2013. Too sad – VS2013 does not support [VLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Hence, I had to do it in mind but I got it running.

As already recommended in one of my comments, I chose `char` as board element instead of `char*`. I could've solved it for `char*` as well but I feel that `char*` could've been an "accidental" choice in the OP.

Following the idea of Eric, I made a type for the 2D board array:

```
typedef char Board[NROWS][NCOLS];
```

The more important is probably the second:

```
typedef char (*PBoard)[NCOLS];
```

Remember that arrays in function parameters are always compiled as pointers. C never passes arrays as arguments. Hence, if we call a function with an argument of type `Board` we will receive an argument of type `PBoard`.

Please, note the parentheses around `*PBoard` – this grants that `PBoard` is a pointer to array. If you remove them you get an array of pointers instead – big difference and not what is intended.

Having mastered this, things in `showBoardVariadic()` become rather easy.

The array of boards is declared as:

```
PBoard boards[nArgs];
```

The assignment with `va_arg` is simply:

```
boards[i] = va_arg(ap, PBoard);
```

The access to the boards is simply:

```
printf(" %c", boards[i][row][col]);
```

This might be surprising but in this case the pointer to array behaves like an array of arrays. It just has a different type. (E.g. you should not use `sizeof` with `PBoard` as in this case the different types would take effect.)

As every board element contains the same contents in this state of development, I was afraid whether issues in board indexing could be unnoticed. Therefore I implemented an alternative initialization where each first element of column gets another character: for `playerBoard` `'a' + row`, for `opponentBoard` `'A' + row`. This test assignment is activated by defining the macro `CHECK`. In my test session, I compiled once with `-D CHECK` once without.

Btw. if you wonder why I introduced `NROWS` and `NCOLS`: While writing this answer I realized that I wouldn't notice if I accidentally flipped rows and columns somewhere as they have equal size in OP. Thus, I separated things and tested with `NROWS` ≠ `NCOLS`. Phew – it still worked properly.

Last but not least, my sample session in Cygwin (as I'm on Windows 10):

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.4.0

$ gcc -std=c11 -D CHECK -o testVarArgMDimArray testVarArgMDimArray.c 

$ ./testVarArgMDimArray
 a ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     A ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 b ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     B ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 c ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     C ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 d ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     D ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     E ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 f ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     F ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 g ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     G ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 h ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     H ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 i ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     I ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 j ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

$ gcc -std=c11 -o testVarArgMDimArray testVarArgMDimArray.c 

$ ./testVarArgMDimArray
 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~     ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

$
```

`typedef` – very clever Eric...

Answer (score 1):

The C specification of `va_arg` requires “The parameter *type* shall be a type name specified such that the type of a pointer to an object that has the specified type can be obtained simply by postfixing a ***** to *type*.” The string `char*[][BOARDSIZE]` does not satisfy this. You should use a `typedef` to give a name to the type.

Additionally, in the parameter list of a function declaration, `char*[][BOARDSIZE]` is automatically adjusted to `char*(*}[BOARDSIZE]`. In a `va_arg` (or `typedef`), it is not. You should use the adjusted form.

So, you should define a name for a type that is a pointer to an array of `BOARDSIZE` pointers to `char`:

```
typedef char *(*MyType)[BOARDSIZE];
```

You should change `boards` to be an array of these rather than an array of arrays:

```
MyType boards[numArgs];
```

and you should change `va_arg` to use the new type:

```
boards[i] = va_arg(ap, MyType);
```

Also note that you are setting every element of the boards to the string "~". This sets them all to point to a string literal, which is likely not what you want. You are not allowed to modify characters in this string literal, so the only way to change what the boards contain is to change them to point to different strings.

If each board element is going to be a single character, you should use `char` instead of `char *`. If they are going to be a fixed or small number multiple characters, you might want an array of `char` instead of a pointer to `char`. If they are going to be a considerable number of multiple characters, you may want to use `char *` but allocate space for each board element.