# How to pass a two-dimensional array to a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays

My function prototype is

```
int** rotate(int **arr, int row, int col, int fl);
```

where `arr` is the two dimensional array, `row` and `col` is the number of row and columns of the 2D array respectively, `fl` is a flag variable. If the value of `fl` is `0` then the array will be rotated right, if fl is `1` then the array will be rotated left.

I have called the function as follows:

```
int **res= rotate(arr, row, col, fl);
```

But I got one warning and one note

```
[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'rotate' from incompatible pointer type.

[Note] expected 'int **' but argument is of type 'int (*)[20]'
```

Comment: [Have a read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: Did you declare arr as follows:  int **arr

Comment: Yet another answer: [SO: Variadic C function printing multiple 2-D char arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593733/7478597). Aside from dealing with var. args, it covers passing a 2D array to a function which still can be used as 2D array.

Comment: You should post all the code needed to understand the question, such as the declarations of all variables you're passing at the call site. But this has been asked and answered many times anyway. Seriously, just search Google for _stackoverflow c pass 2d array_.

Comment: "`arr` is the two dimensional array," --> Not quite `arr` is a [pointer to pointer to int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+**arr).  Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays even though their usage appears similar.

Answer (score 3):

A pointer to a pointer is different from a pointer to an array. Array-to-pointer decaying can only happen on the left-most side (e.g. `int [3][20]` to `int (*)[20]`).

Change your function declaration to

```
int** rotate(int (*arr)[20], int row, int col, int fl);
```

or more obviously,

```
int** rotate(int arr[][20], int row, int col, int fl);
```

Note you have to fix the size at compile-time.

Comment: Why suggest `typedef`ing a pointer, which is generally a bad idea? And this seems confusing, since OP can't declare `Array arr;` and expect this to work. Why not simply `rotate(int arr[][20], int row, int col, int fl);` or `rotate(int (*arr)[20], int row, int col, int fl);`? OP has not provided enough code to clarify what is expected of the return value `int **`.

Comment: @DavidBowling Please suggest me a way to use this in the function's return value.

Comment: I don't follow... to use what in the function's return value?

Comment: @DavidBowling OP's function prototype is `int** rotate(...)`

Comment: yes, that is OP's function prototype, which seems likely to be a mistake also. I suspect that `arr` is declared as a 2d array like `int arr[20][20]`, and that the return value is used to access the rotated array; but how? I imagine that there are further errors here which a [MCVE] from OP would clarify.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports variable length arrays then the function declaration can look the following way

```
void rotate( size_t row, size_t col, int arr[][col], int fl);
```

or

```
void rotate( size_t row, size_t col, int arr[][col], _Bool fl);
```

In this case you can use arrays with different sizes.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rotate( size_t row, size_t col, int a[][col], _Bool fl )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < ( fl ? row : col ); i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < ( fl ? col : row ); j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[fl ? i : j][fl ? j : i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

#define N1  3

int main(void) 
{
    int a[][3] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 }
    };

    rotate( sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ), N1, a, 0 );
    putchar( '\n' );

    rotate( sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ), N1, a, 1 );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 4 
2 5 
3 6 

1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

Otherwise if within the function you are going to create new arrays then the function can look as it is shown in the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ** rotate( size_t, size_t, int a[][*], _Bool fl );

int ** rotate( size_t row, size_t col, int a[][col], _Bool fl )
{
    int **p = malloc( col * sizeof( int * ) );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < col; i++ )
    {
        p[i] = ( int * )malloc( row * sizeof( int ) );
    }

    if ( fl )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
        {
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < col; j++ )
            {
                p[col - j - 1][i] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
        {
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < col; j++ )
            {
                p[j][i] = a[row - i - 1][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return p;
}

#define M   2
#define N   3

int main(void) 
{
    int a[M][N] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 }
    };

    int **p = rotate( M, N, a, 0 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", p[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        free( p[i] );
    }
    free( p );

    p = rotate( M, N, a, 1 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", p[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        free( p[i] );
    }
    free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
4 1 
5 2 
6 3 

3 6 
2 5 
1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

From the example, I assume that you are using a static definition of `arr`.

The Pointer to pointer is not the same as a 2D array.

Change

```
int** rotate(int **arr, int row, int col, int fl);
```

to

```
int** rotate(int arr[][20], int row, int col, int fl);
```

Note that the no of columns will have to be defined before compilation.